# Visualforce Page: Save both HTML5 Canvas and other text

Tags: visualforce, javascript, canvas

I'm experimenting with [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-capture-an-e-signature-and-attach-it-to-a-record-in-the-salesforce1-a).

I'm trying to expand the area that is saved (i.e. saving both the Canvas AND any body text placed on the Visualforce page). I've been trying to add a line in the

> "function saveSignature()
>   {...ehsSignatureExtensionController.saveSignature(signatureBody,image,handleResult);..."

part of the VFP. This doesn't work. I thought it would be part of the @RemoteAction line that was "....string signatureBody...." in the Controller.

What am I missing here? The goal would be that on button click, everything on the Visualforce page would save, not just the Canvas section.

---Updated for Json's comment---

The below will be put on a Contact Object via Lighting Page. The below code will save the drawing within the purple canvas; the code will not save text within the div id="signatureBody" on the Visualforce Page. How can the code be adjusted to save both the drawing within the purple canvas AND the text within the div id="signatureBody"?

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Contact" extensions="ehsSignatureExtensionController">

<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<apex:stylesheet value=" 
{!URLFOR($Resource.jquerymobile,'/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"  />
<apex:includeScript value=" 
{!URLFOR($Resource.jquerymobile,'/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js')}"/>

<canvas id="signatureCanvas" width="400" height="100" style="border: 1px solid white; background-color: purple;"/>  
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/48.0/connection.js"/>

<script>

sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_Id}";
var canvas = document.getElementById("signatureCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouseButton = 0;
var lastX = lastY = null;
var ehsId = '{!Contact.Id}';

function saveSignature() {

var image = canvas.toDataURL().split(',')[1];
ehsSignatureExtensionController.saveSignature(ehsId,image,handleResult);
ehsSignatureExtensionController.saveSignature(signatureBody,image,handleResult);
}

function handleResult(result,event) {
if(result.success) {
    window.top.location.href='/'+ehsId;
} else {
    alert('Error: '+result.errorMessage);
}
}

function handleEvent(event) {
if(event.type==="mousedown"||event.type==="touchstart") {
    mouseButton = event.which || 1;
    lastX = lastY = null;
}
if(event.type==="touchcancel" || event.type==="touchcancel" || event.type==="mouseup") {
    mouseButton = 0;
    lastX = lastY = null;
}
if((event.type==="touchmove" || event.type==="mousemove") && mouseButton) {
    var newX, newY;
    var canvasX = 0, canvasY = 0, obj = event.srcElement || event.target;
    do {
        canvasX += obj.offsetLeft;
        canvasY += obj.offsetTop;
    } while(obj = obj.offsetParent);
    if(event.targetTouches && event.targetTouches.length) {
        newX = event.targetTouches[0].clientX - (canvasX/2);
        newY = event.targetTouches[0].clientY - (canvasY/2);
    } else {
        newX = event.offsetX;
        newY = event.offsetY;
    }
    if(!lastX && !lastY) {
        lastX = newX;
        lastY = newY;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
        context.lineTo(lastX,lastY,lastX,lastY);
        context.stroke();
    } else {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
        context.lineTo(newX,newY);
        context.stroke();
        lastX = newX;
        lastY = newY;
    }
}
if(event.type=="touchmove" || event.type==="mousedrag" || (event.type==="selectstart" && (event.srcElement||event.target)===canvas)) {
    event.returnValue=false;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedrag",handleEvent,true);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",handleEvent,true);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",handleEvent,true);
window.addEventListener("mouseup",handleEvent,true);
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart",handleEvent,true);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove",handleEvent,true);
window.addEventListener("touchend",handleEvent,true);
window.addEventListener("selectstart",handleEvent,true);

</script>
<div id="signatureBody">some text goes here</div>
<apex:form >
<apex:commandButton value="Save Signature" onclick="saveSignature();return false;" styleClass="button"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Exit"/>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ehsSignatureExtensionController {

private final Contact ehs;

public ehsSignatureExtensionController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
ehs = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
}

@RemoteAction public static RemoteSaveResult saveSignature(Id ehsId, String signatureBody) {
Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId=ehsId, name='So11', ContentType='image/png', Body=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(signatureBody));
Database.saveResult result = Database.insert(a,false);
RemoteSaveResult newResult = new RemoteSaveResult();
newResult.success = result.isSuccess();
newResult.attachmentId = a.Id;
newResult.errorMessage = result.isSuccess()?'':result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
return newResult;
}

public class RemoteSaveResult {
public Boolean success;
public Id attachmentId;
public String errorMessage;
}

public pageReference cancel(){
pageReference page = new PageReference('/'+ehs.id);
page.setRedirect(true);
return page;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? also if you can clarify exactly what's your goal and issue ('expand the area that is saved' is not so clear to me).

Comment: I just added some clarity and the code.

Comment: It looks like you have some syntax errors on the remote action part on the client side, did you run a simple test (passing just the signature) just to see if the remote function actually works? Check out this page to see the right syntax for remote actions https://jsforce.github.io/blog/posts/20150405-querying-salesforce-without-consuming-api-quota.html